# Ghost items in javafx ListView with custom ListCell

Tags: java, javafx

I try to view a custom object in a ListView using a custom ListCell. As an example to demonstrate the problem I chose `java.util.File`. Also for demonstration purpose I disable the ListCell directly when rendered. The items are added by an external process simulated by the thread. Everything looks nice until I apply the CSS coloring the disabled ListCell. Now it seems that there are some ghost items which get disabled together with the ListCell they are created of.

How can I solve this?

> App.java

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage )
    {   
        final ListView<File> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setCellFactory( column -> { 
            return new ListCell<File>()
            {
                protected void updateItem( File item, boolean empty )
                {   
                    super.updateItem( item, empty );

                    if( item == null || empty )
                    {
                        setGraphic( null );
                        return;
                    }

                    setDisable( true );                 
                    setGraphic( new TextField( item.getName() ) );
                }
            };
        });

        new Thread( () -> {
            for( int i=0 ; i<10 ; ++i )
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep( 1000 );
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final int n = i;
                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    listView.getItems().add( new File( Character.toString( (char)( (int) 'a' + n ) ) ) );
                });
            }       
        }).start();

        Scene scene = new Scene( listView );    
        scene.getStylesheets().add( "app.css" );

        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception
    {
        super.stop();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {       
        launch( args );     
    }
}
```

> app.css

```
.list-cell:disabled {
    -fx-background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the `disable` property back to `false`. You need to do this for empty cells. The following could happen to a `Cell`:

1. a item is added to the `Cell` and the cell is disabled
2. the item is removed from the `Cell`, the `Cell` becomes empty, but it remains disabled.

In general when a `Cell` becomes empty, any changes done to the `Cell` when an item was added should be undone.

Furthermore you should avoid recreating the `TextField`s every time a new item is assigned to a `Cell`.

```
listView.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new ListCell<File>() {

        private final TextField textField = new TextField();

        protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item == null || empty) {
                setDisable(false);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setDisable(true);
                textField.setText(item.getName());
                setGraphic(textField);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems as if you released my mental block. Although I can not test it until tomorrow I am quite sure that this solves the problem. Your hint not to recreate the visual items every time is quite useful, but is in this case owed to the demonstration.

Comment: Little annotation: also bound properties have to be reset for empty items `disableProperty().unbind()`

Comment: @DaRich: Yes, but only if you bind them when a item is added. Just undo all the changes done when adding an item...