# JavaFX ListView CellFactory Disables Item Selection

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a class with a few values (`ListItem`), and I would like to display a list of these items (`ListView<ListItem>`). `ListItem` has a `value` property which I would like the `ListView<ListItem>` to display as its text, but otherwise the list should look and function normally, particularly regarding item selection. I have the following code to accomplish this. FXML is omitted out of laziness, it's just a `<ListView />`.

```
// Controller for FXML
public class MainController {
    // Wrapper class containing several values
    private class ListItem {
        private String value;

        public ListItem(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        ... // Other useful stuff
    }

    @FXML private ListView<ListItem> list;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        // Set list to display using the given CellFactory
        list.setCellFactory((list) -> {
            return new ListCell<ListItem>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ListItem item, boolean empty) {
                    if (empty) return;

                    // Display item's value property
                    setText(item.getValue());
                }
            };
        });

        // Add test data
        list.getItems().add(new ListItem("test"));
        list.getItems().add(new ListItem("test2"));

        // Print when selection changes
        list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((evt) -> {
            System.out.println("Selection changed!");
        });
    }
}
```

This displays the `ListItem` correctly, using its `value` property within each item of the `ListView`. However, it breaks the selection, and the `System.out.println(...)` does not execute (the item also does *not* highlight in the GUI either). I have discovered that removing the `list.setCellFactory(...)` statement is the culprit, but puts me in a tight spot.

When `list.setCellFactory(...)` is present, the item uses the *correct* text, but *cannot* be selected. When `list.setCellFactory(...)` is absent, the item uses the *wrong* text, but *can* be selected. Is there something else special I need to do in order to display the text correctly *and* select the item?

I've done the prerequisite Googling, but I couldn't find anyone else with this particular issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to James_D's answer it's a good idea to undo any changes done to the cell, when a item is removed. Otherwise you get issues like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38483552/2991525 . Set the `text` to `null` or `""` for empty cells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add

```
super.updateItem(item, empty);
```

as the first line of `updateItem(...)`. This call *must always* be present in an overridden `Cell.updateItem(...)` method (the same is true for other `updateXXX` methods, such as `updateIndex(...)`).

In addition, you should also make sure that your `updateItem(...)` method handles all cases correctly, including the case where cells are empty:

```
protected void updateItem(ListItem item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
    } else {
        // Display item's value property
        setText(item.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly the issue. I'm more familiar with C# and was thinking of it like a lambda, so it didn't occur to me to call the super class. Thanks for the help as well as the advice on the `empty` case.